# How to prove that Radón-nikodým theorem fails in this case?

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

[image]

In this exercise 8.M I have already shown that the collection of sets given forms an $\sigma$-algebra and that $ \lambda, \mu $ are measures and that $\lambda \ll \mu$. I could not show that the Radón-nikodým theorem fails, but I think that perhaps with a contradiction argument assuming the existence of f satisfying the Radón-nikodým theorem and finding a suitable set can solve the problem. But I could not define such a set. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hint: from $\lambda(\{x\})=0$ and $\mu(\{x\})=1$ you get $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I think I understand. First noting that $f$ can not be identically zero, I can take $x$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ In doing so, we have $\int_{ \{ x\}} f d \mu = 0$,  using the hint. Then $f(x)=0$ contradiction. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  Equivalently, we have $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$ using $\{x\}\in\mathbf{X}$, which won't recover $\lambda(X)=\infty$.

Comment: I understood. Thanks a lot for the help!